# User.Identity.Name returns different strings in different servers

Tags: asp.net, iis, active-directory, forms-authentication, windows-authentication

I have an ASP.NET WebForms application. In one server, `User.Identity.Name` returns a string such as "**domain/username**". In another server, it returns only "**username**". Which configuration I should look into in server to make them to have the same behavior?

Environment:

- .NET Framework 4.5.2 is used
- Windows Authentication is enabled. Anonymous is disabled.
- ApplicationPoolIdetity is used as application pool ID
- Integrated mode is used in application pool

Comment: What versions Windows on each server? Are any of the servers a member of Active Directory?

Comment: We're using Windows Server 2008 R2 in both servers. They both are in domain

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this helps, but I have a web app that is also configured for Windows authentication and Anonymous is disabled... just like yours.  My web server machine is joined to the same domain as the users who are accessing the web site from their client machines.  When I display **User.Identity.Name** in the website, I'm getting **domain\username** on the screen.  That's what you should be seeing.  If one of your servers is showing only "username", that's very strange indeed, and I'm not sure what the issue is, but that's the server I think you need to investigate for configuration problems.